# splitting text files based column wise

Tags: linux, split, centos, command-prompt

So I have an invoice that I need to make a report out of. It is on average to be about 250 pages long. So I'm trying to create a script that would extract the specific value of the invoice and make a report. Here's my problem:

1. the invoice is in pdf format with it spanning two column. In Linux command, I want to use 'pdftotext' Linux command to convert into multiple text files (with each txt file representing each pdf page). How do I do that
2. I recognize that 'pdftotext' command splits it left part of the page and right part of the page by having 21 spaces in between. How do I the right side of the data(identified after reading at least 21 spaces in a row) to the end of the file
3. Since the file is large and I only last few page of the files, how do I delete all those text files in a script (not manually) until I read a keyword (let's just say the keyword = Start Invoice)?

I know this is a lot of questions, but I'm confused in what Linux command can do. Can you guys guide me to the right direction? Thanks

PS: I'm using `CentOS 5.2`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
pdftotext YOUR.pdf | sed 's/^\([^ ]\+\) \{21\}.*/\1/' > OUTPUT
pdftotext YOUR.pdf | sed 's/.* \{21\}\(.*\)/\1/' >> OUTPUT
```

But you should check out `pdftotext`'s `-raw` and `-layout` options too. And there are more ways to do it...